# block image detection

Tags: image

i want to detect color from a pixelated image, and then, turn the specific pixel into different color?

for example:
pixel with B/G/R < 150 re-color it to white. and pixel with B/G/R > 150 to black or stay.

is it possible? if yes, how? i need guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to convert your image into HSV Color Space!

You can Mask out Blue color from the Image using [inRange](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) function as follows:

```
Mat mInput_Bgr,mInput_HSV,mBlueMask,mDestination;
mInput_Bgr= imread(FileName_S,1);
imshow("mInput_Bgr",mInput_Bgr);

cvtColor(mInput_Bgr,mInput_HSV,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
inRange(mInput_HSV,Scalar(104,200,0),Scalar(132,255,255),mBlueMask);// You can play with all the values to choose your desired color
imshow("mBlueMask",mBlueMask);
mInput_Bgr.setTo(Scalar(255,255,255),mBlueMask);// You can set what ever Color Value
imshow("Corrected_mInput_Bgr",mInput_Bgr);
```

[image]